# How to display DataFrame in Databricks?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I recently started working with Databricks and I am new to Pyspark. I am trying to display a tidy and understandable dataset from a text file in pyspark.

Here is the code snippet:

```
# File location and type
file_location = "/FileStore/tables/2014_GE_By_Precinct.txt"
file_type = "txt"

# The applied options are for txt files. For other file types, these will be ignored.
df = spark.read.option("inferSchema", "true") \
  .option("header", "true") \
  .csv(file_location)

df.show(truncate=False)
```

Here is the result I am getting:

[image: Here is the result I am getting]

I want the dataframe to be displayed in a way so that I can scroll it horizontally and all my column headers fit in one top line instead of a few of them coming in the next line and making it hard to understand which column header represents which column.

Answer (score 1):

In Databricks, use `display(df)` command.

```
%python
display(df)
```

Read about this and more in [Apache Spark™ Tutorial: Getting Started with Apache Spark on Databricks](https://www.databricks.com/spark/getting-started-with-apache-spark/dataframes).